# Bulma Navbar overflow on the right because there is too many elements

Tags: html, css, navbar, bulma

I have a Bulma Navbar and there is too much elements in it which cause it to overflow on the right of the page. Is it possible to make a second line ?

```
<nav class="is-dark has-background-white">
  <div class="navbar-brand is-hidden-desktop">
    <div class="navbar-burger">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <span>Text Here</span>
          <div class="navbar-dropdown">
          <a class="navbar-item">
           Overview
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item">
           Elements
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item">
           Components
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item">...</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-end">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you please provide more context to the problem? Like how many elements are there? How long are the elements? Is it possible that you can provide code to the problem area?

Comment: There is for the moment 15 items in the navbar (it's generated by the admin of the website so it could be more), element can be 20+ chars long, that's why I would like to make it go to the next row, I'll update the question with some code

Comment: I know nothing about Bluma, but from the understanding that I have gained in the past few minutes, Bluma uses flex containers, so have you tried changing the `flex-wrap` to `wrap` for the navbar in question?